# How to bind lists with different rownumbers or dataframes with different column names directly one below another

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I need to wrap up my for loop which creates lists of lists of integers. The loop iterates trough folders, extracts pixel values for ~13 images in each folder. I need to combine the results of these different folders together. I want to combine them vertically, one bellow another, into a dataframe (they have the same number of columns).  What I want looks like this for one folder (without for loop):[Data.frame result of iteration trough one folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMOS0.jpg)

I want my result to look like in the picture, with results of each next iteration pasted bellow last row of the previous one. Columns present each folder.

I tried to:

1) keep them in one list and then tried to "as.data.frame" all the results together, but i get the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
TRUE,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 63
```

because the row numbers differ. The problem is the rownumbers will always differ in my case, and i need to get past that problem.

2)create a list for each folder, create data.frame out of each and then rbind the data.frames together, but i get the following

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names
```

I do not care about the column names, they will also always be the same. I just want to paste the results of the each iteration of the loop in one file, one iteration vertically below the other. Anyone knows how to get past this problem?

This is how the list of lists looks like (before converting it to dataframe) for one folder called L2A_T33TYL_20170604T094031_AOT_20m:

"
    $L2A_T33TYL_20170604T094031_AOT_20m
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMOS0.jpg) 165 166 162 162 204 207 205 210 261 261 260 261 353 357 349 353 340 340 
    341 343 360
    [22] 363 361 366 441 443 443 443 262 262 266 264 209 209 209 209 266 261 265 
    230 233 230
    [43] 232 221 225 223 225 342 338 339 336 312 309 312 309 327 328 298 293 328 
    328 298 293

```
$L2A_T33TYL_20170604T094031_B02_20m
[1] 153 132 146 134 209 214 150 149 216 191 181 202  88  66  95 102 214 209 
208 182 203
[22] 230 215 216 299 263 305 308 241 176 161 192 138 155 131 133 146 152 163 
195 152 175
[43] 213 155 197 192 370 248 275 267 243 271 252 225 216 113 142 164 170 157 
172 148 134

$L2A_T33TYL_20170604T094031_B03_20m
[1] 524 438 450 491 568 541 493 486 744 649 657 678 448 423 422 494 670 694 
658 624 553
[22] 520 544 556 797 663 848 804 873 601 588 678 431 488 420 464 449 429 522 
613 506 604
[43] 555 419 534 482 639 552 528 577 601 761 679 574 527 447 427 511 489 569 
567 471 506".
```

When i put only this list of lists to dataframe i get no problems because all lists are of same length. The next iteration (trough next folder T33TYJ L2A_T33TXJ_20170604T094031_VIS_20m) is gonna have a list of lists of another length. In the for loop the joined list of lists looks like this:

```
"$L2A_T33TXJ_20170604T094031_VIS_20m
 [1] 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40  0  0  0  0  
 0  0  0  0
 [29]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 42 42 42 42 40 40 40 40 
  40 40 40 40
 [57] 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 40 40 40 40 41 41 41 41 40 40 40 40 
 40 40 40 40
 [85]  0  0  0  0 40 40 40 40  0  0  0  0 40 40 40 40

 $L2A_T33TXJ_20170604T094031_WVP_20m
 [1] 1488 1487 1488 1487 1488 1487 1488 1487 1489 1488 1489 1488 1689 1675 
 1676 1681 1488
 [18] 1488 1488 1488    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    
 0    0    0
 [35]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1488 1488 1488 1488 
 1488 1488 1488
 [52] 1488 1538 1488 1487 1488 1778 1775 1734 1763 1488 1488 1488 1488 1488 
 1488 1488 1488
 [69] 1488 1488 1488 1488 1488 1488 1488 1488 1833 1488 1488 1607 1488 1488 
 1488 1488    0
 [86]    0    0    0 1488 1488 1488 1488    0    0    0    0 1488 1488 1488 
 1488

 $L2A_T33TYL_20170604T094031_AOT_20m
 [1] 165 166 162 162 204 207 205 210 261 261 260 261 353 357 349 353 340 340 
 341 343 360
 [22] 363 361 366 441 443 443 443 262 262 266 264 209 209 209 209 266 261 265 
 230 233 230
 [43] 232 221 225 223 225 342 338 339 336 312 309 312 309 327 328 298 293 328 
 328 298 293"
```

Here you can find the code I used to get this done. [rbind data.frames with same number of columns but different number of rows in a for loop, exactly one bellow another (vertically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041205/rbind-data-frames-with-same-number-of-columns-but-different-number-of-rows-in-a)

Comment: Hey, your question is a bit unclear. Can you paste some code (even with simulated data) which shows how the data looks after you read it, but before you do something with it?

Comment: Hi, i edited the question. Is further clarification needed?

Comment: Yes, the clarification is needed. Please provide the code for this procedure, both you are using and for simulation of your data (or some pieces of your data). 
So. You want to get a dataframe, where each row is pixels from a file, right? What are columns then?

Comment: Code is here on another question i posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041205/rbind-data-frames-with-same-number-of-columns-but-different-number-of-rows-in-a). Should I put it here in edit (the text will be even longer than it is now)? For the simulation I posted another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080518/put-nested-lists-of-different-lengths-into-a-dataframe-one-bellow-another) since I am grasping for the straws. Yes. The rows are pixels extracted on different locations (thus the different row lengths), and columns are images from each folder.

Comment: So the data in the same row are not related? Instead of storing them as a data.frame, how about a list of vectors?