# Put nested lists of different lengths into a dataframe one bellow another

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, nested

How can i put this lists of lists together in a dataframe, inside a for loop? That is, how do I bypass the error:

```
 Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names =  
 TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 30, 20
```

Code:

```
ListA=list(firstA=1:50, secondA=1:50,thirdA=1:50)
ListB=list(firstB=1:30, secondB=1:30, thirdB=1:30)
ListC=list(firstC=1:20, secondC=1:20, thirdC=1:20)

NestedList=list(ListA,ListB,ListC)

DataToWrite=list()

for (i in 1:length(NestedList)){
    DataToWrite=c(DataToWrite,NestedList[i]) 
    }
#at the next step i get the error 
df=as.data.frame(DataToWrite)
```

What i want is to add each list in the for loop to in the same columns of the previous one, at the end of the previous list, in a dataframe. What i want looks like in the picture:
[example of structure that I would like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWSPe.jpg)

I do not care about the column names, I would like to keep the names of the first list. Note that the list "columns" names will be different for each list and that may also present a problem when merging to data.frame.

Comment: Fyi, some packages can do this directly, eg, `library(data.table); rbindlist(NestedList, id = "src")` which adds a column to identify "source data.frame" for the resulting rows.

Comment: Thank you, this solution also works perfectly in this case.  Do you have any idea why wouldn't it work in this example i posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074159/how-to-bind-lists-with-different-rownumbers-or-dataframes-with-different-column ? I get the error "  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list", even though my variable after the loop is typeof="list".

Comment: Your data there is a list of numeric vectors, not a list of lists. If you want to convert it to the latter (so each element of each vector corresponds to a column in the result), maybe use `rbindlist(lapply(x, as.list), id="src")`..? If lengths differ, you can read about the `fill=` option by typing `?rbindlist`.

Comment: Wow, so there are different types of lists... It is frustrating that i cant just simply put one list with same number of columns bellow another with the same number and save it as a data.frame. Why is this such an issue. I tried this "  DataToWrite=rbindlist(lapply(c(DataToWrite,rasterOut[3]),as.list),fill=TRUE,id="src")" and got the error "  fill=TRUE, but names of input list at position 1 is NULL. All items of input list must have names set when fill=TRUE."

Comment: Oh, right. Because it is creating a table, it needs column names. Maybe using `as.data.table` instead of `as.list` will fix it (since that function auto-generates names).

Comment: Hmm i get crashes if I try to use this as a solution. Anyways, i decided to just put the results of the loop in a dataframe for which I have defined specific column names. Therefore i can use rbind on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(NestedList, function(x)as.data.frame(x, col.names=c("First", "Second", "Third"))))
```

gives,

```
    First Second Third
1       1      1     1
2       2      2     2
3       3      3     3
4       4      4     4
5       5      5     5
6       6      6     6
7       7      7     7
8       8      8     8
9       9      9     9
10     10     10    10
11     11     11    11
12     12     12    12
13     13     13    13
14     14     14    14
15     15     15    15
16     16     16    16
17     17     17    17
18     18     18    18
19     19     19    19
20     20     20    20
21     21     21    21
22     22     22    22
23     23     23    23
24     24     24    24
25     25     25    25
26     26     26    26
27     27     27    27
28     28     28    28
29     29     29    29
30     30     30    30
31     31     31    31
32     32     32    32
33     33     33    33
34     34     34    34
35     35     35    35
36     36     36    36
37     37     37    37
38     38     38    38
39     39     39    39
40     40     40    40
41     41     41    41
42     42     42    42
43     43     43    43
44     44     44    44
45     45     45    45
46     46     46    46
47     47     47    47
48     48     48    48
49     49     49    49
50     50     50    50
51      1      1     1
52      2      2     2
53      3      3     3
54      4      4     4
55      5      5     5
56      6      6     6
57      7      7     7
58      8      8     8
59      9      9     9
60     10     10    10
61     11     11    11
62     12     12    12
63     13     13    13
64     14     14    14
65     15     15    15
66     16     16    16
67     17     17    17
68     18     18    18
69     19     19    19
70     20     20    20
71     21     21    21
72     22     22    22
73     23     23    23
74     24     24    24
75     25     25    25
76     26     26    26
77     27     27    27
78     28     28    28
79     29     29    29
80     30     30    30
81      1      1     1
82      2      2     2
83      3      3     3
84      4      4     4
85      5      5     5
86      6      6     6
87      7      7     7
88      8      8     8
89      9      9     9
90     10     10    10
91     11     11    11
92     12     12    12
93     13     13    13
94     14     14    14
95     15     15    15
96     16     16    16
97     17     17    17
98     18     18    18
99     19     19    19
100    20     20    20
```

---

So, `lapply` goes through the list converting each element (i.e., each nested list) to a data frame and giving the columns the same names. `do.call` then binds these data frames together using `rbind`.

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted to. I am puzzled how this actually works and will need to examine the interaction of do.call, lapply, and function(x). But this is it. Thank you! I think I will be able to implement this solution to my original problem which is very similar to this, but inside a for loop (if u are interested see links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074159/how-to-bind-lists-with-different-rownumbers-or-dataframes-with-different-column).

Comment: @davorkorman I've added a few words of explanation to try and clarify what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! However, I can not wrap my mind why this solution doesn't work in this example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074159/how-to-bind-lists-with-different-rownumbers-or-dataframes-with-different-column). It makes no sense to me. There I also have an ireggular nested list (two lists with different row length) with 14 columns each. I have concatenated them together in the for loop, and after the loop when I try your solution I get all the results in ONE column?